# Xcode 7 swift, ''no method declared with objective-c selector (function)" warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I want to add an action to a button, but I heard that the code below does not work. Does anyone know the way to add an action to a button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("function:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Here is the code 
I am using Xcode 7.3.1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 80, 30, 30))

func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

print("button pressed")

}

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(button)

}
```

Comment: Why is the code not working? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: its not working because the function wont start when the button is pressed. Im pretty sure there is an updated way to do it. I want to know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that your problem is with the `Selector` part.

In Swift 2.2 the selector syntax was changed so you now get a compile time check for your selectors. You can read more about that [here](https://swift.org/blog/swift-2-2-new-features/).

To answer your question, this syntax:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(function(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

should make you and - more importantly in this case (sorry :)) - the compiler happy.

### Update (after looking at the code you provided)

You need to move the `pressed` function outside of your `viewDidLoad` function so that it is a separate function.

So your code ends up looking like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 80, 30, 30))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func pressed(sender: UIButton) { //As ozgur says, ditch the !, it is not needed here :)
    print("button pressed")
}
```

And that seems to work, I can see `button pressed` in my console now at least.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: it tells me to add objc to the function declaration. but when I do that xcode tells me to remove objc

Comment: @Ice3343 Is the `function` a `private` method? If so please delete `private`.

Comment: @Ice3343. Could you show us the code? And one other thing...which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: You need to show us how you defined `function`. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @ozgur I put the code in the question. I use Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: @Ice3343 You don't need `!` at the end of `UIButton` and **pressed** should be defined outside of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Ice3343, I've updated my answer, see if that doesn't help you

Comment: @ozgur yes removing ! and moving the function ''pressed'' outside of viewDidLoad did work

Comment: great...glad we got it working in the end, thanks for the help @ozgur :)

Answer (score 0):

Try These

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

your method

```
func buttonAction (sender:UIButton)
{
}
```